# Database in embedded linux (PetaLinux)

Tags: mysql, linux, flash, storage, zynq

I'm working on a project with my Zynq SoC (TE0720) where I want to store some data into the NAND flash memory. I'm not so familiar with either Linux and databases. The goal is store some data for logging and view them on a tablet.

The data will change frequently so it needs to be stable.
Can someone give me some advice on what I should choose? I really appreciate that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SQLite. I've seen and implemented several variants of such databases for embedded systems. There is no need to launch any database service, like in case with MySQL for example. You'll be able to use SQL queries to obtain, modify or insert any information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have some good documentation or getting started link for me? Is it difficult to get it communicate with an app in Android tablet?

Comment: Use searching in google :). I don't have any certain link for this issue. Also try to find out how does Android SDK support interaction with SQlite databases. I think all these answers you may find in Internet with google and a patience.